# Android- Retrieve image from SQLite, using Parcelable

Tags: android, sqlite, android-imageview, parcel

I can't retrieve image stored as blob from SQLite database. I'm using Parcel. Below is my code. I want to show the image in imageView called `galerie_foto_retrieve`. Now the app shows error. And I can't run it. I'm beginner in android so have you got any ideas what I'm doing wrong. I would be grateful for any help!

**DataProvider**

```
private byte[] byteArray;

public DataProvider(byte[] byteArray)

this.byteArray=byteArray;

protected DataProvider(Parcel in) 
{
byteArray = new byte[in.readInt()];
in.readByteArray(byteArray);
}

 @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) 
{
dest.writeInt(byteArray.length);
dest.writeByteArray(byteArray);
}
```

**DataListActivity**

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {byte[] byteArray;
                        byteArray = cursor.getBlob(210);
DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(byteArray);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, RetrieveData.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data", (DataProvider) listDataAdapter.getItem(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
byte[] byteArray;
    ImageView galerie_foto_retrieve;    

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle!=null){
                DataProvider dataProvider = bundle.getParcelable("data");
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray.length);
                galerie_foto_retrieve.setImageBitmap(b);
```

**DbOperace**

```
public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {
FormDatabase.FormularovaDatabaze.IMAGE1
        };
        cursor = db.query(FormDatabase.FormularovaDatabaze.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor;
        }
        else
        {
            return cursor;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! My mistake was in file Retrieve data 
this is right solution, if someone want to know that

```
byteArray=dataProvider.getByteArray();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
galerie_foto_retrieve.setImageBitmap(b);
```